# Salesforce CTI Implementation Service Console

Tags: force.com, service-cloud-console, servicecloud, cti, softphone

I am preparing for service cloud consultant exam. I have a little bit of experience in supporting CTI integration issues as salesforce developer due to my current project.

But there are few points i need to clear regarding **CTI integration In Service console**.

**Below are my queries -**

1. From scratch As a salesforce developer what is the key responsibility for CTI Integration in Salesforce service console ?
2. What i should recommend to client if they ask for CTI implementation in their service console application ?
3. What need to be done from a salesforce developer end-point and customer end point. what is the process ?

Please advise!

**Thanks

Nirmallya**

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of these are the "correct" answers but they are what make sense to me:

> > From scratch As a salesforce developer what is the key responsibility for CTI Integration in Salesforce service console ?

Screen pop entities which match phone numbers and create call log related to those entities to record details of the call.

> > What i should recommend to client if they ask for CTI implementation in their service console application ?

Since CTI implementations are generally tied to the phone system you're using I'd start by checking with the phone system vendor.  If you haven't picked a phone system then you could make support for an Open CTI Call Center adapter a requirement.  If you already have a phone system and it doesn't support open CTI then your only option would be to develop an Open CTI based Call Center adapter using an appropriate vendor supported CTI interface.

> > What need to be done from a salesforce developer end-point and customer end point. what is the process ?

See last response...

Comment: Appreciate your response. 

If client try to implement service cloud CTI functionality in salesforce, below are the scenario need to take care As per my understanding - 
a) Install a appExchange Product in Saleseforce .i.e. Avaya which contains Visualforce fage(Softphone Screen) and a controller.
  
b) Now question is - In Which number customer is suppose to call ?  
c) When the call comes which parameter comes to salesforce ?